# Retrieve number of messages in CloudQueue based on condition

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-queues, azure-storage-emulator

I'm using Azure Storage Emulator. I have a CloudQueue and some messages. 
I want to retrieve the number of messages where Dequeue Count is greater than 3 for example.

I can do a loop for all the messages and increment a counter when a message has a Dequeue Count > 3 but I would like to find an optimized alternative.

How can I apply filters after fetching the queue ?

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnection"];
CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("testQueue");
queue.CreateIfNotExists();

queue.FetchAttributes();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can do a loop for all the messages and increment a counter when a
>   message has a Dequeue Count > 3 but I would like to find an optimized
>   alternative.

AFAIK, that's the only way as Azure Storage Queues do not provide any server-side filtering mechanism based on message attributes. You will need to fetch the messages and apply filtering on the client side only.

Here's the sample code that peeks at top 32 messages from the queue and examines `DequeueCount` property of the message:

```
        var account = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);
        var queueClient = account.CreateCloudQueueClient();
        var queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("myqueue");
        queue.CreateIfNotExists();
        var messages = queue.PeekMessages(32).ToList();
        for (var i=0; i<messages.Count; i++)
        {
            var message = messages[0];
            if (message.DequeueCount > 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Message has been dequeued more than 3 times. Do something!");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I apply filters after fetching the queue ?

Comment: What SDK you're using? Please edit your question and include the code for fetching the messages.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Azure Service Fabric

Comment: Thanks. PeekMessages() can peek a maximum of 32 messages, but is there a way to peeks all messages ? (~1000 msg)

Comment: Unfortunately no. An alternative would be to call `GetMessages()` and make the message invisible for long enough duration so that you can loop through all messages. However please keep in mind that calling `GetMessages()` will dequeue the messages and will increase the dequeue count.\